# Problem verifying expression with 3D vectors

Tags: vector, tensors

I am unable to verify that my vector expressions are equivalent. I want it to say true or false.

```
 Remove["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = e ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]
$Assumptions = a ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]
$Assumptions = p ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]
p = a - (a.e) e
TensorExpand[p.p] == (a.a - a.((a.e) e) - ((a.e) e).a + ((a.e) e).((a.e) e))
(a.a - a.((a.e) e) - ((a.e) e).a + ((a.e) e).((a.e) e)) == ((a - \
(a.e) e).(a - (a.e) e))
TensorExpand[p.p] == Norm[a]^2 - (a.e)^2 (*e has length 1*)
```

What I ultimately want is to find (using mathematica) is the angle between vectors a and b. I'm given the lengths of a and b as 156 and Dot[a,e]== Dot[b,e]==90. vectors p and q are the projections of a and b onto a plane. Angle between p and q is 120. Now I have this code that is no good.

```
   $Assumptions = (a | e) \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals] && e.e == 1 && 
   a.e == b.e == 90  && Sqrt[a.a] == 156 == Sqrt[b.b]; 
   p = a - (a.e) e;
   q = b - Dot[b, e] e;
   Simplify[TensorExpand[a.b], Sqrt[a.a] == 156 == Sqrt[b.b]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can prove  using TensorExpand

```
TensorExpand[p.p] == (a.a - a.((a.e) e) - ((a.e) e).a + ((a.e) e).((a.e) e))
(* True *)
```

Comment: why is p vector's colour  black while a and e are blue? How can I get the absolute value of a vector as Abs[] function is for reals or complex not vector?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) just once, instead of 3 different times. In your code, the only assumption Mathematica uses is `p ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]`. Also, use `a.a` instead of `Norm[a]^2`. Finally, you also need to include your condition that `e.e == 1`. So:

```
$Assumptions = (a | e) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
p = a - (a.e) e;
Simplify[
    TensorExpand[p.p == a.a - (a.e)^2],
    e.e == 1
]
```

> True

**Addendum**

To address the OP question about assumptions, you can combine assumptions using [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And) (&&):

```
$Assumptions = (a | e) ∈ Vectors[3,Reals] && e.e == 1;
p = a-(a.e) e;
Simplify @ TensorExpand[p.p==a.a-(a.e)^2]
```

> True

[`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) will not use the `e.e == 1` assumption, so you will need to include [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) to take account of that assumption.

As for an angle assumption, do you have an example?

Comment: Is it possible to combine within the same $Assumption statement the attributes that a is a 3-D vector with its Euclidean length? I don't know how to specify that a vector has a particular length other than through its dot product in Mathematica. Can the known angle between two vectors in the same plane also be given as a general assumption?

Comment: Vectors p,q  in the same plane are projections of vectors a and b resp.The angle between p and p is 120 degrees. p and q in terms of a and b are:-p=a-(a.e)e;  q=b-(b.e) e. Can this information be used as assumptions to calculate the dot product of a with b?

Comment: Vectors a and b have the same length of 156 and same dot product with unit normal vector e  Dot[a,e] =Dot[b,e].=90.

Comment: By calculating Dot[a,b] in terms of vectors p and q, ultimately I wish to find the angle between vector a and vector b.